# Apply Filters On WordPress Header

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've Created a function in my WordPress plugin to Apply Filters on WordPress header.
I want to Change and remove the content of the `Get_header()` hook on WordPress, is There any way to do this? (Like the header and footer builder plugin For elementor that removes the current header and replace this with another one.)

Comment: The content that you want to remove is from the theme?, because wordpress load the header.php in the themes, so I sugest that check the header.php in the theme and check what is you want to remove but this is not recommended, what in specific you wanna achieve?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm working on a plugin so I don't have access to the header.php in plugin. I want to find a way to remove and change header content by a WordPress Hook.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest this

first dump all the current action from wp_head, with

```
global $wp_filter;
var_dump($wp_filter['wp_head']);
```

and then remove all those are not from wordpress
this are wordpress default actions

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_resource_hints', 2 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet' );
add_action( 'publish_future_post', 'check_and_publish_future_post', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_robots', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_styles', 8 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_custom_css_cb', 101 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_site_icon', 99 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_post_preview_js', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', '_custom_logo_header_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_maybe_inline_styles', 1 ); // Run for styles enqueued in <head>.
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_host_js' ); // Back-compat for sites disabling oEmbed host JS by removing action.
```

do not remove those, because are wordpress default, then when you have indentified what are those theme actions remove with

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'name_of_the_theme_action_to_remove');
```